# How can I quickly render html/xhtml from the windows clipboard

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

I'm curious to know if there might be a plugin for chrome/firefox out there that will enable me to quickly have the contents rendered by the browser?  Actually, any other programs would work as well.  I know I can just copy it into a file, but I'm looking for the quickest way possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a blank window in Firefox, then open Firebug. Click 'Edit' on the HTML tab and paste the HTML code into it.